# Display scheduled routines actual 'Done' time in agenda view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I scheduled routine to wake in the morning at 5:00, and get it done at 5:12 this morning

[image]

If it is displayed the actually done moment of the routine could be more helpful.

However, it does not.

[image]

Update:

Even worse that The scheduled jobs disappeared after rebuilding the agenda rather than presented as the scheduled moment as DONE status.

How could config the agenda view to show the real finished time?

Comment: if timestamp is changed from inactive to active, the done scheduled jobs will appear in the agenda, only in status of NEXT rather than DONE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timestamp for the `DONE` state does not appear in your `org-agenda` because it is an inactive timestamp. This is the difference between regular timestamps and inactive ones: the regular timestamps trigger an entry to show up in the agenda while the inactive ones don't. This leads us to our first potential solution (which you've already tried): manually changing these inactive time stamps to be active ones. When `org-agenda` parses an active time stamp, it puts an entry for the associated task in the agenda at that time. The problem here is that the task's `TODO` status is `NEXT` since the repeated task has already shifted to its next occurrence. Thus the `org-agenda` entry will have `NEXT` as its status, rather than `DONE`. (It's worth noting here that changing the `CLOSED` timestamp on a non-repeating task to be active won't cause it to show up in the agenda at that time.)

Alternatively, we can make the org-agenda show us inactive time stamps. There are a couple of ways to do so:

- In the agenda view, press either `[` or `]`, which will cause the inactive time stamps to appear.
- Set the variable `org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps` to `t` and reload the agenda.

This is also less than ideal. Once again, the agenda entry is marked `NEXT` due to the shifted TODO status of the repeated task. Additionally, (for me, at least), the item shows up twice. One of these is from the logbook while the other is from the `LAST_REPEAT` property.

Fortunately org-agenda offers better options for viewing the timestamps for completed tasks with `org-agenda-log-mode`. In the agenda view, `org-agenda-log-mode` can be activated with `l` (the letter between "k" and "m"). This still isn't quite sufficient to show repeated task completion timestamps. By default `org-agenda-log-mode` only shows tasks which were closed or were clocked in. As stated above, this task has not been closed since it shifted to the next repeat. However, org-agenda is also capable of displaying timestamps for tasks which have changed status. Since the logged task changed from `NEXT` to `DONE`, its timestamp will show up under this view. We can activate this view in a few different ways:

- Calling `org-agenda-log-mode` with the universal argument (`C-u l`).
- Adding `state` to `org-agenda-log-mode-items` e.g. `(setq org-agenda-log-mode-items '(closed clock state))`.
- Setting `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` e.g. `(setq org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed clock state))`. This option will cause agenda to start in `org-agenda-log-mode` and is the best choice if you always want to see this information when you open your agenda.

It should be noted that while the completed task will show up here, it will still have the `NEXT` tag. However, it will also show that its state changed to `DONE` at this time (see the last image below for an example).

---

**Example**

As an example, here is a short `org-mode` file with a repeating task ("Wake Up") that has already been completed once. For demonstrative purposes, this file also has another repeating task that has not been completed, a one-time task that has been closed and another scheduled task that has not been finished but has been clocked in:

```
#+SEQ_TODO: NEXT(n) TODO(t) | DONE(d)
* Items
** NEXT Wake up
   SCHEDULED: <2019-06-11 Tues 05:00 +1d>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LAST_REPEAT: [2019-06-10 Mon 13:37]
   :END:
   :LOGBOOK:
   - State "DONE"       from "NEXT"       [2019-06-10 Mon 13:37]
   :END:
** DONE One time event
   CLOSED: [2019-06-10 Mon 13:46] SCHEDULED: <2019-06-10 Mon 15:00>
** Not going to be finished
   SCHEDULED: <2019-06-11 Tue>
   :LOGBOOK:
   CLOCK: [2019-06-10 Mon 13:54]--[2019-06-10 Mon 13:54] =>  0:00
   :END:
** Go to bed
   SCHEDULED: <2019-06-10 Mon 22:00 +1d>
```

After calling `org-agenda`, we see that the timestamp for our completed "Wake Up" does not show up:
[image: The timestamp for the completed repeated task does not appear]

Allowing inactive timestamps will let the the completed "Wake Up" timestamp show up, but the timestamp shows up twice and its not very clear what these agenda items are referring to:
[image: Allowing inactive timestamps allows the logged timestamp to appear, but the associated agenda item is not very clear]

Calling `org-agenda-log-mode` gives more relevant agenda entries (and is sufficient for having the closing timestamp for one-time tasks appear). However, it does not show status changes by default, which means that our "Wake Up" timestamp will not appear:

[image: org-agenda-log-mode allows closed items' timestamps to appear as entries]

Modifying `org-agenda-log-mode` to show timestamps for changed state, we finally see our closed "Wake Up" timestamp.
[image: Using org-agenda-log-mode and setting it to show state allows the timestamp to show up with information that shows that its TODO status was changed]

Comment: can I ask which theme you are using?

Comment: @Stefan 
I use zenburn with a few minor adjustments (which aren't visible in these screenshots). A few faces end up being a little to close to the background color which makes them hard to see. In particular, I changed the highlight face, lazy-highlight face, and the four swiper-background-match-face faces. I think the highlight and lazy-highlight ones have been changed in the past year or so, so they may no longer be an issue.